# unordered_set::find and noexcept

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

I have the following unordered_set:

```
class ArtifactImpl{...};

class ArtifactSetKeyOps
{
  public:
    std::size_t operator()(const ArtifactImpl& artifact) const noexcept;
    bool operator()(const ArtifactImpl& lhs, const ArtifactImpl& rhs) const noexcept;
};

std::unordered_set<ArtifactImpl,
  ArtifactSetKeyOps,ArtifactSetKeyOps> artifactSet_;
```

Note that my hash and predicate template argument/s have a noexcept specification.

- Would it be possible for unordered_set::find to throw?

I'm aware that find isn't marked noexcept, but in practice find should not perform allocations...

- Would it be acceptable to call find from a noexcept marked function?

e.g:

```
const ArtifactImpl& foo() noexcept
{
  auto pos = artifactSet_.find(key);
  //etc...
}
```

Even though foo() here above goes against find's noexcept specifications, I'm wanting to know whether the specification holds practically iff one provides one's own **noexcept** hash and comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** `noexcept` seems useful only for move constructor/assignment operator.

If you would dare to accept [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/find/) or even me as sufficient authority: it does not throw any exception, unlessan aspect does - such as the allocator or a comparator throws, nothing throws.
(I should probably go dig out the relevant ISO passages now...)

However, as to my understanding, `noexcept` isn't particulary useful here:

[Andrzej has a detailed explanation on his blog](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/noexcept-what-for/), from which I (mis)quote the relevant parts here:

- `noexcept` doesn't buy much if the implementation throws despite the specification
- it doesn't help with implementing a no-throw exception safety guarantee
- and it is unlikely to enable significant optimizations except in one case, related to move semantics:

> for certain functions, like `vector<T>::push_back` using move constructors/assignments of `T` instead of copy constructors/assignments can dramatically increase performance. However, if this move constructor/assignment can potentially throw, `push_back` would loose the strong exception safety guarantee. In order to take an advantage of the move operations (where possible) and at the same time keep the strong guarantee, there needs to be a way to determine if a given move operation is potentially throwing or not, and use it or alternatively fall back to good old copying. This is exactly what function `std::move_if_noexcept` does, but it needs T’s operations to be marked as noexcept where appropriate.

Comment: Your answer is informative. I was under the impression that dynamic throw specifications (including no throw) were replaced entirely by noexcept, from here:

"noexcept is an improved version of throw(), which is deprecated in C++11. Unlike throw(), noexcept will not call std::unexpected and may or may not unwind the stack, which potentially allows the compiler to implement noexcept without the runtime overhead of throw()." at:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

Comment: I have a piece of code that just performs a search, and IMO it should be impossible that it throws, and hence I wanted to add the specifier. This also eases the testing (that would involve injecting an exception that should never happen...), and handling it, inorder to ensure a higher code coverage...:-(. Would you in such a case rather use a nothrow specifier?

Comment: > *Would you in such a case* - it seems that no one really knows for sure yet; but the pendulum swings towards *"Put it whereever it fits, since it doesn't do harm (AFAweK)"* Under this assumption, I would say, yes, your `foo` should be noexcept, the only difference is that you get `std::terminate` rather than an (unexpected and thus most likely unhandled) exception.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It could throw if you hash function (which it must call) throws.  For that reason alone I wouldn't use it.</strike>  But more importantly,  I wouldn't use the `noexcept` specifier because it goes against the `find` function's specifications.

Comment: Note that I've provided an explicit hash function that has a noexcept specification. I'm already aware of everything you've said.

Comment: @WernerErasmus Sorry, I missed that.  But I stand by my second statement.

Comment: The please edit the first part of your answer. The second part is not helpful, but is true, yes.